# How to Bind the text of Selected Item in Angular

Tags: angular

I know how to do this in AngularJS but I am finding it difficult to do in Angular4.x

I have this;

```
<select id="taxTypeId" name="taxTypeId" [(ngModel)]="tax.taxType" class="form-control">
   <option *ngFor="let tt of taxTypes" value={{tt.id}}>{{tt.name}}</option>
</select>
{{tax.taxType.name}}
```

I want to bind the selected text (name property) for whatever value selected. Please help.

Comment: I find the question unclear. The selected item will be the one where `tt.id` is the same as `tax.taxType`.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do. When an item is selected from the drop-down, I want the selected text to appear beneath the dropdown. I hope you understand now

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I fully understand the question. It's also not clear how `tax` and `taxType` looks like exactly, but this might do what you want:

```
<select id="taxTypeId" name="taxTypeId" [(ngModel)]="tax.taxType" class="form-control">
   <option *ngFor="let tt of taxTypes" [ngValue]="tt.taxType">{{tt.name}}</option>
</select>
{{tax.taxType?.name}}
```

(use `ngValue` instead of `value` and the `?` before `.name` might not be necessary - just in case to prevent an error when nothing is selected)